# Vue, Vuetify - Reduce space between buttons in toolbar

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I've tried everything to reduce the space between the buttons, so that they all sit nicely centered and evenly spaced in the toolbar when on mobile, but for some reason the space next to the left-most button remains, while the right-most button is slightly over the right edge, as seen in the pic below.

Here's the last thing I tried before coming to ask a question here:

```
<!-- Notice the "ma-0 pa-0" that I've now added in literally everywhere -->
<v-toolbar fixed color="teal lighten-1" dark class="hidden-md-and-up ma-0 pa-0">
    <v-toolbar-items class="ma-0 pa-0">
        <v-btn 
            flat 
            v-for="link in navigation" 
            :key="link.text" 
            :class="{ 'teal lighten-2':link.active }" 
            @click="$vuetify.goTo(link.link, { duration:1000, offset:60, easing:'easeInOutCubic' })"
            class="mobile ma-0 pa-0"
        >
            <v-icon>{{ link.icon }}</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
    </v-toolbar-items>
</v-toolbar>
```

I've also tried things like creating a custom style rule (non-scoped, otherwise Vuetify seems to ignore 'em) like `.v-btn.mobile { margin:0; padding:0 }` to no avail, and trying all the different `justify-` attributes.

Other than that I've also tried different Vuetify elements like `v-footer`, and adding in `v-container`s, `v-layout`s and `v-flex`s. None of which seem to work.

[image]

The image is a screenshot from my phone, while connected to the vue dev server on my pc on the same network, in case that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The padding comes from the `.v-toolbar__content` element created by vuetify.
Unfortunately vuetify doesn't provide a straight-forward way to get rid of this padding.

However you can easily override this with a custom style:

```html
<v-toolbar fixed color="teal lighten-1" dark class="my-toolbar hidden-md-and-up">
  <v-toolbar-items>
    <v-btn 
      flat 
      v-for="link in navigation" 
      :key="link.text" 
      :class="{ 'teal lighten-2':link.active }" 
      @click="$vuetify.goTo(link.link, { duration:1000, offset:60, easing:'easeInOutCubic' })"
      class="mobile"
      >
      <v-icon>{{ link.icon }}</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </v-toolbar-items>
</v-toolbar>
```

With the following style (assuming you're using plain css)

```html
<style scoped>
.my-toolbar >>> .v-toolbar__content {
  padding: 0;
}
</style>
```

You're right, you can't style the vuetify-generated elements directly, but you can keep the `scoped` styles by using [deep selectors](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements)
(the `>>>` in the example, you might need to use `/deep/` or `::v-deep` if you're using a css preprocessor)

Edit: For centering and stretching the buttons you just need to remove the `v-toolbar-items` and give the buttons the `block` attribute and the `fill-height` class, e.g.:

```
<v-toolbar fixed color="teal lighten-1" dark class="my-toolbar hidden-md-and-up">
  <v-btn 
    flat
    block
    v-for="link in navigation" 
    :key="link.text" 
    :class="{ 'teal lighten-2':link.active }"
    @click="$vuetify.goTo(link.link, { duration:1000, offset:60, easing:'easeInOutCubic' })"
    class="mobile fill-height"
  >
    <v-icon>{{ link.icon }}</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
</v-toolbar>
```

If you only want to center the items, you could use something like this:

```
<v-toolbar fixed color="teal lighten-1" dark class="my-toolbar hidden-md-and-up">
  <v-btn 
    flat
    v-for="link in navigation" 
    :key="link.text" 
    :class="{ 'teal lighten-2':link.active }"
    @click="$vuetify.goTo(link.link, { duration:1000, offset:60, easing:'easeInOutCubic' })"
    class="mobile fill-height ma-0"
  >
    <v-icon>{{ link.icon }}</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
</v-toolbar>

<!-- with the following style: -->
<style scoped>
.my-toolbar >>> .v-toolbar__content {
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: center;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hey, that's great! And thanks for the deep selector tip, I didn't even know that was a thing. D'ya also perhaps know of a way that I can now center the buttons within the nav (either literally centering them, or evenly spacing them across the nav)? Because currently the all clump up on the left side.

Comment: @PrintlnParams I added two more examples on how to get the buttons stretched or centered :)

Comment: You're literally the bomb. Thank you!